# How to change comment from a XML element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a XML file that has a comment under the element. is there any way to remove the comments using lxml ?

```
<TEST name="1">
  <!--  test values: 1, 2, 3-->
  <file name="test1.py" /> 
</TEST >
<RESULT name="r1" value="false">
  <!--  result values: true, false-->
</RESULT >
```

I want to change the comment under the element "TEST" to:

```
<TEST name="1">
  <!--  test values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5-->
  <file name="test1.py" /> 
</TEST >
<RESULT name="r1" value="false">
  <!--  result values: true, false-->
</RESULT >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = '''
<head>
<TEST name="1">
  <!--  test values: 1, 2, 3-->
  <file name="test1.py" />
</TEST >
<RESULT name="r1" value="false">
  <!--  result values: true, false-->
</RESULT >
</head>
'''

tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//head/TEST/comment()"):
    bad.text += ', 4, 5'

print(et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<root>
<TEST name="1">
  <!--  test values: 1, 2, 3-->
  <file name="test1.py" /> 
</TEST >
<RESULT name="r1" value="false">
  <!--  result values: true, false-->
</RESULT >
</root>'''

r = etree.fromstring(html)
comments = r.xpath(r'//comment()')
for c in comments:
    p = c.getparent()
    p.remove(c)
print (etree.tostring(r))
```

out:

```
b'<root>\n<TEST name="1">\n  <file name="test1.py"/> \n</TEST>\n<RESULT name="r1" value="false">\n  </RESULT>\n</root>'
```