# How do I search and replace a large block of text?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xmllint, ex

I only have awk, sed, xmllint and ex available to me.

I need to modify a text file. What it is now:

```
        <!--
        <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                   maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
                   enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   scheme="http" proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="80"/>
        -->
```

I need to remove the XML comments and change the proxyName variable. What I need to change it to:

```
        <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                   maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
                   enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   scheme="http" proxyName="proxy.company.com" proxyPort="80"/>
```

There are several instances of this block in this file. I only want to change the block that contains:

```
scheme="http" proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="80"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Better to use `xmllint`, not `sed` for this

Comment: I do have access to xmllint. Can you give me a starting point to investigate?

Comment: @DavePearce all Unix tools have man pages so your starting point would me typing `man xmllint` or just googling it, e.g. at https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint. You could also try [googling xmllint edit comment](https://www.google.com/search?q=xmllint+edit+comment) or similar - I see one result of that query in particular you might be interested in at [how-to-change-comment-from-a-xml-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543482/how-to-change-comment-from-a-xml-element) with answers using `python` to edit the XML.

Comment: @DavePearce click on the tag xmllint and follow the link 'learn more' If this is not useful, update said link with links you found useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use xmllint you can *probably* use xmlstarlet. If so, you can use XSLT to do this. Unfortunately xmlstarlet only supports XSLT 1.0 so it's not a pretty solution, but it works.

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<doc>
    <!--
    <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="http" proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="80"/>
    -->
    <foo/>
    <!--
    <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="http" proxyName="ignore.me" proxyPort="80"/>
    -->
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="comment()[
        contains(.,'scheme=&quot;http&quot;') and 
        contains(.,'proxyName=&quot;&lt;subdomain>.&lt;domain>.com&quot;') and 
        contains(.,'proxyPort=&quot;80&quot;')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'proxyName=&quot;&lt;subdomain>.&lt;domain>.com&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:text>proxyName="proxy.company.com"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'proxyName=&quot;&lt;subdomain>.&lt;domain>.com&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command line/Output** (This can be redirected to an output file.)

```xml
==> xmlstarlet tr test.xsl input.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="http" proxyName="proxy.company.com" proxyPort="80"/>
    <foo/><!--
    <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
               maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="http" proxyName="ignore.me" proxyPort="80"/>
    --></doc>
```

Comment: Should the `>`s in `contains(.,'proxyName=&quot;&lt;subdomain>.&lt;domain>.com&quot;')` be `&gt;`s?

Comment: @EdMorton - They can be `&gt;`, but they don't have to be. [See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax) (this is the XML 1.1 spec, but it's the same in [XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a XML sample as

```
<context>
            <!--
        <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                   maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10"
                   enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   scheme="http" proxyName="subdomain.example.com" proxyPort="80"/>
        -->
    <other>test</other>
</context>
```

Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract comment content to a variable
comm="$(xmllint --xpath 'normalize-space(/context/descendant::comment()[contains(.,"example.com")])' tmp.xml | sed -ze 's/\n/\&#xA;/g')"
# get everything else
content="$(xmllint --xpath '/context/*[not(descendant::comment()[contains(.,"example.com")])]' tmp.xml | sed -ze 's/\n/\&#xA;/g')"
# set contents again

printf "%s\n" 'cd /context' "set ${comm} ${content}" 'save' 'bye' | xmllint --shell tmp.xml
```

Comment turned into element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context><Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="48" maxPostSize="16777216" minSpareThreads="10" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="http" proxyName="subdomain.example.com" proxyPort="80"/>
 <other>test</other>
</context>
```

Next, change the attribute value as described here
[Modifying in line attribute in XML using xmllint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062426/modifying-in-line-attribute-in-xml-using-xmllint/77064272#77064272)